# Aggregate function on composite user type

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a composite user type that represents a monetary amount. This type spans to two columns.

```
-Amount
-Currency
```

When i am creating an HQL query that performs an aggregate function like "avg" on a property using this composite user type an exception is thrown. The reason as it seems is that AvgFunction cannot operate with types that have multiple columns.

Is there any way to use CompositeUserType in aggregate functions?

Thanks in advance and best regards
Stathis Alexopoulos

Comment: Could you show us your query?

Comment: select avg( bill.fullAmount) from BillBean as bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't make much sense. What would be the average of these three rows?

```
amount    currency
5         USD
10        EUR
15        YEN
```

You may average the amounts and neglect the currency:

```
select avg(bill.fullAmount.amount) from BillBean as bill
```

but you can't average the monetary amounts (i.e. the tuple [amount, currency]).

Comment: Thanks a lot about the hint. Hibernate recognized the property amount.